# How to flash message in Laravel after api post request with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, post, request

**Goal**

Flash a message after a post request is saved successfully to database.

**Problem**

The message doesn't appear when a post request comes from a react frontend. If the react frontend receives a success message it reload the page, as you can see in the `handleSubmit` function.
When a request is send from a form generated in the "standard laravel way", everythin works, like expected.

So here is the code:

ReportsController:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

...

public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $report = new Report([

      'name' => $request->get('name'),

      'body' => $request->get('body'),

      'visible' => $request->get('visible'),

      'show_in_slider' => $request->get('show_in_slider')

    ]);

    if ($report->save()) {
      Session::flash('success', 'Feedback gespeichert!');
      return response()->json(['success' => true, 'url' => '/admin/reports'], 200);
    }
  }
```

The line in the `api.php`

```
Route::resource("reports", "ReportsController");
```

The blade for the messages:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
<div class="warning-modal">
  {{$error}}
</div>
@endforeach
@endif

@if(session("success"))
<div class="alert-modal">
  {{session("success")}}
</div>
@endif

@if(session("error"))
<div class="warning-modal">
  {{session("error")}}
</div>
@endif
```

The corresponding functions snippets in the React frontend.

`handleSubmit`:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const response = await saveData("/api/reports", report);
        if (response.success) {
            window.location = response.url;
        } else {
            alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
        }
    }
```

Sending the post request in the `saveData` function:

```
export default async function saveData(api, data) {
    const token = document
        .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
        .getAttribute("content");
    const url = window.location.origin + api;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}
```

So where is the fault?

Thanks for your time in advance :)

**Edit**

I solved it without reloading the page and let JavaScript handle the alert. Thanks to elyas :)

```
export default async function PostData() {
    const report = await CollectData();

    const response = await SaveData("/api/reports", report);

    const alert = document.createElement("div");
    alert.innerHTML = response.message;
    if (response.success) {
        alert.className = "alert-modal";
        ToggleNewReport();
    } else {
        alert.className = "warning-modal";
    }

    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(alert);
}
```

Depending on the response i add the corresponding alert.

Comment: Since that is an AJAX call, just pass that in JSON response and output it with JS if value is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the javascript async functionality, and your page doesn't reload after send post data. So you can put your message in json data and show it via javascript. 
in your Controller:

```
if ($report->save()) {
  return response()->json(['success' => true, 'url' => '/admin/reports', 'success'=> 'Feedback gespeichert!'], 200);
}
```

And in JS file:

```
if (response.success) {
        alert(response.message);
        window.location = response.url;
    } else {
        alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats, how i will do it :)
So i can simply close the modal without reloading the page and show small message with JavaScript :)

Comment: Yes , that's wright. you can optionally use the sweet alert library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert

Comment: I'm tryin to code most of the things by my self so that i will learn most :) But thanks for the hint, it works now :)